# Field name doesn't have default value error while using factories in Laravel 8

Tags: php, database, laravel, factory

Here my UserFactory :

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Faker\Factory as FakerFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'firstname' => $this->faker->firstName(),
        'name' => $this->faker->lastName,
        'nickname' => $this->faker->userName,
        'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Here the first part of my User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasLocalePreference
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $appends = ['avatar','targetLang','targetLangId','type', 'isAdmin'];
    protected $casts = [
        'preferences' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $guarded= [];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','accessToken','refreshToken',
    ];
```

And the test where i call the factory :

```
class MoveCourseItemTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test to move card in other block.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMoveCard() {

        // Create Teacher User
        $teacher = factory(User::class)->create([
            'isTeacher' => 1,
            'termsofuse_id' => 1,
            'privacypolicy_id' => 1,
        ]);
```

Finally i get this error, only on staging environment (not on local environment) :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
> 1364 Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into
> `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `remember_token`, `isTeacher`,
> `termsofuse_id`, `privacypolicy_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
> values (Kenneth Altenwerth Jr., koch.cooper@example.org,
> $2y$10$1B7LlTzM4iINkVI/82Pp6OHSUWBWaePPdDKMy1DRW2K02d8UYKc2S,
> r0WnPBrZGG, 1, 1, 1, 2021-07-29 21:12:54, 2021-07-29 21:12:54))

Anyone know how i can solve it ? Thanks !

Comment: if field is not nullable then just pass `''` in `firstname` as `'firstname' => ''`

Comment: I will note that the insert call uses columns `name, email, password, remember_token, isTeacher, termsofuse_id, privacypolicy_id, updated_at, created_at` which are don't include `firstname` or `nickname` as well (even though they are in the factory you shared) which may indicate you've defined another user factory somewhere else and is conflicting? You also seem to be mixing Laravel 8 style `use` and `namespace` declarations with legacy style globals. What version of Laravel are you using and if you're using L8 are you using the legacy factory adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it nullable in your migration:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Comment: It's bad practice to change your production code to make a test pass. There is a reason the field was made not nullable.

@ken 's answer provides a solution that fixes the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional note, if you write a constructor for the model, make sure to pass the `$attributes` array to the parent constructor, or else all the attributes will not be passed to the model `create` method.

Example

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me , that you do not have firstname column in your table. Create it and make it nullable by default as others said.